# Windows Threading C++/CLI: How to pass managed parameters to threads

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, parameter-passing, managed-c++

I'm trying to multithread an originally single-threaded windows program of mine.

What i can't find is how to pass pointers to managed objects to the threads (sorry if my terminology fails).

To make it clear:

```
typedef struct {
    CVideoGeneral^ videoInput;
} ThreadParameters;

void Thread(void* params)
{
    ThreadParameters* p = (ThreadParameters*)params;
    // go on...
}
```

This will not compile giving an error:

> Error 1   error C3265: cannot declare a managed 'videoInput' in an
>   unmanaged '$UnnamedClass$0xe11f725b$1$'

I am asking how can i make a struct that contains such managed pointers that is compatible with and can later be passed to the threads as a parameter. Giving up on managed stuff and replacing them with unmanaged plain ones is unfortunately not an option.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Isn't there a managed thread class that you can use?

Comment: I don't know. I am new to C++ / CLI and i chose this way of threading after a tutorial i read. I have used pthreads in the past for unix and given that the parameter requirements were about the same (a pointer to void) i guess that this way of passing parameters to threads is somewhat standard.

Comment: You can see what this guy does and maybe use that: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2074/Managed-threads-in-Managed-C